# Is it possible to put different datatypes in the same List<>

Tags: list

Is it possible to put different datatypes in the same List<> in C#?

myList.Add("Joe");

myList.Add(25);

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java, yes.  Everything is an Object in Java and Arrays take Objects.  Good luck getting them back out though.